# How to grep a specific pattern before match?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm currently working on multiple configuration files which use the following format:

```
[Stanza1]
action.script=1
action.ping=0
action.lookup=1
action.notable.param=0
action.script.filename=script.pl
[Stanza2]
action.script=0
action.ping=0
action.lookup=1
[Stanza3]
action.script=1
action.ping=0
action.lookup=0
action.script.filename=script.pl
```

I want to know which stanzas include "action.script.filename=script.pl", so the expected result would be

```
[Stanza1]
[Stanza3]
```

Using something like:

```
grep -B 10 "action.script.filename = script.pl" file
```

doesn't work for cases where the stanza name is more than 10 lines before the match, and proves quite cumbersome to use.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The following `sed` command would do the trick :

```
sed -n '/^\[/h;/^action\.script\.filename=script\.pl$/{x;p}'
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/U3qoMg).

When it encounters a line that starts with "[", it stores it into its hold buffer. When it encounters a "action.script.filename=script.pl" line, it prints the content of the hold buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this can be done purely with `grep`. I would recommend a small bash script:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ \[.* ]]; then
        # save stanza for later
        stanza=$line
    fi
    if [[ $line =~ action.script.filename=script.pl ]]; then
        echo $stanza
    fi
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
$ awk '/action\.script\.filename=script\.pl/{print h} /^\[/{h=$0}' ip.txt
[Stanza1]
[Stanza3]
```

- `/^\[/` lines starting with `[` character, you can also use something like `/Stanza/` as long as it uniquely identifies header lines

  - `h=$0` for such lines, save the content (`$0`) to variable `h`
- `/action\.script\.filename=script\.pl/` if input line matches the given search criteria

  - `print h` print the value of `h` variable
  - if you are matching whole line, then you can also use string match `$0 == "action.script.filename=script.pl"` instead of regex match

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, works perfectly fine for me =)

Answer (score 1):

This line of code works for me

```
grep '^\[Stanza\|^action.script.filename=script.pl$' fileName | grep -B1 'action.script.filename=script.pl' | grep -v 'action.script.filename=script.pl\|\-\-'
```

Explanation:

```
grep '^\[Stanza\|^action.script.filename=script.pl$' fileName
```

matches either *[Stanza*]* lines or *action.script.filename=script.pl* ones. Output is something like this

```
[Stanza1]
action.script.filename=script.pl
[Stanza2]
[Stanza3]
action.script.filename=script.pl
```

Adding this filter `| grep -B1 'action.script.filename=script.pl'` will result in this

```
[Stanza1]
action.script.filename=script.pl
--
[Stanza3]
action.script.filename=script.pl
```

Now you just need to clean the output from unwanted parts

```
| grep -v 'action.script.filename=script.pl\|\-\-'
```

This is the final output

```
[Stanza1]
[Stanza3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    awk '/^\[.*\]$/{stanza=$0;next} /action.script.filename=script.pl/{print stanza}' filename
    [Stanza1]
    [Stanza3]
```

You can store each stanza in a variable called `stanza` and move to next line. Whenever you see the string `action.script.filename=script.pl` , print the variable `stanza`.